# ionic 2 How to get mimeType from Cordova File Transfer Plugin in ios?

Tags: ios, ionic2, cordova-plugins, mime-types, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing hybrid mobile application.
In one of the scenario we need to fetch mimeType from a file when we select or upload a file.

Android side perfectly work but ios side not working (**this.File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl**).ios related solution available or not ?

```
this.File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(fileUri).then((entry: Entry) => {
    if (entry) {
        var fileEntry = entry as FileEntry;
        fileEntry.file(success => { 
            var mimeType = success.type;
        }, error => {
            // no mime type found;
        });        
    }
});
```